# php login to asp backend

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress

I'm in the final stages of a relatively straightforward frontend redesign/redevelopment of an existing (OLD) asp-based website/infrastructure.

I'm using wordpress, and have pretty solid php skills... but I've never messed with ASP and/or c# and I'm completely dumbfounded about where to even begin. I've searched and dabbled and experimented with everything I can find... but just can't even get it started. Ughs and whatnot... so close to being done!

My question (please please please help!): is there any way (how?) to create a simple php form (or html/whatever) that can live in my wordpress-based nav and log EXISTING users into the EXISTING aspx-based site? Literally just need to open the existing client popup (which is a total clusterf in its own subdomain -- another story altogether).

ANY help would be so very much appreciated. Thz in advance --

Answer (score 1):

Try using curl to send a form post directly to the TARGET of the aspx login form.  http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Comment: MANY thanks -- looks to be a good place to start... brought me here: http://www.mishainthecloud.com/2009/12/screen-scraping-aspnet-application-in.html ... which looks promising. Anyone have any luck with this by chance??